# What does C: means in the output of aapt dump xmltree

Tags: android, aapt

I run command `aapt dump xmltree someApk AndroidManifest.xml`.
Here is a digest of the output:

```
  E: activity (line=461)
    A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0c0001
    A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.huawei.mobilenotes.client.business.display.activity.NoteTagExpandListActivity" (Raw: "com.huawei.mobilenotes.client.business.display.activity.NoteTagExpandListActivity")
    A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
    A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x80
  C: " NoteTagExpandListActivity\n"
  E: activity (line=470)
    A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0c0001
    A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.huawei.mobilenotes.client.business.setting.activity.VerificationLocalPwdActivity" (Raw: "com.huawei.mobilenotes.client.business.setting.activity.VerificationLocalPwdActivity")
    A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
    A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x80
```

I think the E stands for Element and A stands for Attribute, but what does C means?

Also I get the corresponding text int the AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:name="com.huawei.mobilenotes.client.business.display.activity.NoteTagExpandListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/theme"/> NoteTagExpandListActivity
<activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:name="com.huawei.mobilenotes.client.business.setting.activity.VerificationLocalPwdActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/theme"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: E for element, A for attribute and C for content ?

Comment: @Maloubobola after read the [official source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ad3f86a526c49ecd733564771b5c2ce7eade2a96/tools/aapt/XMLNode.cpp), I know C is used when it is a plan text.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ad3f86a526c49ecd733564771b5c2ce7eade2a96/tools/aapt/XMLNode.cpp)

```
else if (code == ResXMLTree::TEXT) {
            size_t len;
            printf("%sC: \"%s\"\n", prefix.string(), String8(block->getText(&len)).string());
    }
```

It seams that it is used for plain text.

#### In summary:

1. N : Namespace
2. E : Element
3. A : Attribute
4. C : Plain Text

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question and accepting that answer ;)